# Android resource compilation failed (System language hindi)

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When my system language is english I am facing no errors but as I change my system langauage to hindi, I am not able to build my project and getting following error :

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  error: invalid configuration 'h७२०dp-v१३' (/Users/rohit/AndroidStudioProjects/AlphaProject/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-h७२०dp-v१३/values-h७२०dp-v१३.xml).

Command: /Users/rohit/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/9aec58eb3edb20acf9016e8a7acb4026/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 compile --legacy \
        -o \
        /Users/rohit/AndroidStudioProjects/AlphaProject/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug \
        /Users/rohit/AndroidStudioProjects/AlphaProject/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-h७२०dp-v१३/values-h७२०dp-v१३.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #2

at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.doCompile(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:142)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.compile(Aapt2Daemon.kt:81)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.compile(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:170)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:37)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:28)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.useAaptDaemon(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:71)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.useAaptDaemon$default(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:69)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.run(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:34)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter$submit$submission$1.run(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:39)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

I already changed the numbers into 1,2,3 format instead of १,२,३ in system settings but still facing the error. Help me to fix this issue.

Comment: "I already changed the numbers into 1,2,3 format instead of .... " - try to do this and remove build folder, and rebuild

Comment: @sharonooo I tried everything from clean to rebuild project & invade cache. Still having the same error.

Comment: Check this file (and folder) name:  values-h७२०dp-v१३/values-h७२०dp-v१३.xml 
 according to the message in log: /Users/rohit/AndroidStudioProjects/AlphaProject/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-h७२०dp-v१३/values-h७२०dp-v१३.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the resource merger in the JVM default locale.

After setting the jvm locale `(e.g. in gradle.properties, org.gradle.jvmargs=-Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en)` all started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your logs indicate the file with the wrong filename still exists in a cache. In order to fix this, Try Build > Rebuild Project.

Comment: tried everything from clean to rebuild project & invade cache. Still having the same error.